# How can I simplify the use of flags with Views Bulk Operations?

Tags: flags, views

I have an administrative display (made with views) that lists content that is pending approval.

In the case of my site, approval means flagging with the *approval_for_pub* flag (which triggers a custom rule).

[VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) allows nodes to be flagged/unflagged all at once by clicking a handy button:

[image: flag/unflag button]

However, upon clicking this button, by default it shows all possible flags and the flag/unflag option:

[image: lists of flags]

This is a problem on my site because **some of the people responsible for approval get confused by the names of the flags and select the wrong option.**  So, what I would like to do is create a VBO option that, when the button is pressed, automatically **flags** all applicable content with the **approval_for_pub** flag.

How can I approach this?

It seems like a small detail, but this step happens several times a day, so the chance of making a mistake is quite high.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the "Flag (or unflag) a node" action directly, create new a rules component and show it in your administrative view.

1. Navigate to *Configuration » Workflow » Rules » Components*
2. Click on *Add new component* , choose *Rule* from the components plugin drop-down menu.
3. Choose a name (e.g. Approve), add a parameter with the type node.
4. Add a condition, choose *Node is flagged* from the drop-down menu.
5. Choose the appropriate flag, select the node-parameter for the node, choose site:current-user for the user on whose behalf the flagging-action will be performed, select *negate* such that the condition will evaluate to true when the node is **not** flagged.
6. Add an action, choose *Flag a node* from the drop-down menu.
7. Choose the appropriate flag, select the node-parameter for the node, choose site:current-user for the user on whose behalf the flagging-action will be performed.

Edit your administrative view, configure bulk operations such that the *Approve* operation is shown instead of the *Flag (or unflag) a node*

Comment: Great solution!  I have used Rules for VBO before but it didn't occur to me that I could apply it in this case as well.